# org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set:[]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting extremely strange behavior out of JPA 2.0

I'm trying to build a query that looks likes, where employeId and empDepartment are long values passing through java arguments

```
Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.empId = :empId and e.empDepartment = :empDepartment");
query.setParameter("empId" ,employeId);
query.setParameter("empDepartment",empDepartment);
```

But the above query doesnt work for first time, it generating the above error but when second time i trigged the same method again every thing went smoothly, this happens each and every time, what could be the reason for it?

Comment: Can you show us the entire method where this is happening?

Comment: You must have some `if` statements around the `query.setParameter` calls  that stop them being executed the first time.  Can you post the full method as @chrylis suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.empId = ? and  e.empDepartment = ?");
query.setParameter(1, employeId);
query.setParameter(2, empDepartment);
```

If this is not working either, than there can be a problem with your query content as well, not with the replacement of the parameters. Maybe the the types are not correct. The parameter type is inferred by the context.

Comment: As per 2021: This way is now NOT recommended. Index-based parametrizing is deprecated and is not supported in latest versions of Spring Data

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.empId=:empId and e.empDepartment=:empDepartment");

query.setParameter("empId" ,employeId);
query.setParameter("empDepartment",empDepartment);
```

I don't know what was the reason, but it happened to me once. Try it like this. Just remove white spaces between =:empId and the other parameter.