# TypedQuery error "Not all named parameters have been set" when they had. JPA / Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to build and execute a dynamic query that looks like this:

```java
String query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE (1=1) AND (UPPER(e.lastName) LIKE :lastName)";

final TypedQuery<Employee> dbQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, Employee.class);
dbQuery.setParameter("lastName", "%" + value.toString().toUpperCase() + "%"));
```

But it fails with this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [lastName]
```

Most interesting is that in debug mod i can see that dbQuery has a bind for "lastName" parameter and contains the specified value inside its "parameterRegistrations" field. So i have no idea.

Alternative with using positional parameters like
 `dbQuery.setParameter(1, "%" + value.toString().toUpperCase() + "%"));` is not my case, so pls lets do not discuss it.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160394/org-hibernate-queryexception-not-all-named-parameters-have-been-set) is similar to mine but it's still unanswered.

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using? Are you sure that there is no typo(upper/lower case) in the parameter name of your real query?

Comment: can you confirm the exception is thrown when you invoke the instruction dbQuery.getResultList()?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys! It was my inattention. A super strange and legacy code was there, which was creating a new instance of TypedQuery much later based on my query, but without parameters. I didn't expect it. That was the reason.